# HTML entities appear to contain nonsense

Tags: html, unicode, encoding, utf-8

```
&#195;&#172;&#226;&#8364;&#185;&#194;&#160;&#195;&#172;&#203;&#339;&#194;&#129; &#195;&#172;&#226;&#8364;&#162;&#203;&#8224;
```

Above is the html, below is the code.  Is this a name? What does it mean?

```
Ã¬â€¹Â Ã¬ËœÂ Ã¬â€¢Ë†
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a **double** [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), data mangled by using incorrect codecs.

It's actually *Korean*, a name:

```
신영 안
```

or, if using HTML entities, this *should* have been encoded to

```
&#49888;&#50689; &#50504;
```

It translates to English as *Shin-Young An*.

When [encoded to UTF-8](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=Encode_text%28'UTF-8%20%2865001%29'%29To_Hex%28'Space',0%29&input=7Iug7JiBIOyViA), and grouped per input code-point then displayed using hex digits you would get this:

```
ec 8b a0
ec 98 81
20
ec 95 88
```

To produce the output you have, someone must have:

- Decoded the above UTF-8 data using [Windows codepage 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), producing

  ```
  ì‹<A0>ì˜<81> ì•ˆ
  ```

  (where `<A0>` is the non-breaking space character, and `<81>` is an invalid CP1252 byte, but this is often ignored in many decoders; I've included them in this notation because they'd not otherwise be printable)
- Encoded the resulting mess to UTF-8 again to give you the following byte values:

  ```
  c3 ac e2 80 b9 c2 a0
  c3 ac cb 9c c2 81
  20
  c3 ac e2 80 a2 cb 86
  ```

  (the grouping matches the correct UTF-8, above)
- Decoded those UTF-8 bytes a second time using the same Windows CP1252 codec, this time producing:

  ```
  Ã¬â€¹Â<A0>Ã¬ËœÂ<81> Ã¬â€¢Ë†
  ```

  (with the same note on the `<A0>` and `<81>` characters)
- Finally encoded the resulting characters to HTML entities:

  ```
  &#195;&#172;&#226;&#8364;&#185;&#194;&#160;&#195;&#172;&#203;&#339;&#194;&#129; &#195;&#172;&#226;&#8364;&#162;&#203;&#8224;
  ```

If you have Python installed, then the [`ftfy` library](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can 'repair' text like this in a single step:

```
>>> import ftfy
>>> sample = '&#195;&#172;&#226;&#8364;&#185;&#194;&#160;&#195;&#172;&#203;&#339;&#194;&#129; &#195;&#172;&#226;&#8364;&#162;&#203;&#8224;'
>>> ftfy.ftfy(sample)
'신영 안'
```

I used that library to tell me what codecs were used, as well as use it's [sloppy CP1252 decoder](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#module-ftfy.bad_codecs.sloppy) to produce the decodes above.

E.g. for your input I used:

```
>>> ftfy.fixes.fix_encoding_and_explain(ftfy.fixes.unescape_html(sample))
('신영 안', [('encode', 'sloppy-windows-1252', 0), ('decode', 'utf-8', 0), ('encode', 'sloppy-windows-1252', 0), ('decode', 'utf-8', 0)])
```

to see the repair plan, and reversed it to explain how the Mojibake was produced in the first place.

Comment: Okay, I am a Police Detective and I subpeonaed cell phone records to identify a subscriber and the name came back as Ã¬â€¹Â Ã¬ËœÂ Ã¬â€¢Ë†

Comment: Then your data has gone through a repeated mangle somewhere. However, no data was *lost*, which could easily have happened as well. It's fully reversible in this case.